# Regex match symbol and ignore exact string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

Currently I have regex like so:

`(?<!&)#(?!8203;)`

This will allow the capturing of most `'#'` for my case.

For instance, given the input `he#ll#o`, there would be 2 matches as expected.

Again, given the input `he#ll#o&#8203;`, there would be 2 matches as expected.

However, given the input `&#&#&#` or just `#8203;#8203;#8203;`, it will fail to find matches.

How do I modify the existing regular expression to ignore exactly `'&#8203;'`, given that the preceding text may not be the end of a previous word or whitespace?

Comment: You need [the best regex trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html): [`&#8203;(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|#`](https://regex101.com/r/34mQ5X/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the lookarounds to

```
#(?<!&#(?=8203;))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tH03Xd/1).

*Details*:

- `#` - a `#` char
- `(?<!&#(?=8203;))` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if - immediately on the left - there is a `&#` char sequence that is immediately followed with `8203;` char sequence.

A synonymous regex will look like

```
(?<!&(?=#8203;))#
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tH03Xd/2). I'd use `#(?<!&#(?=8203;))` since the lookbehind check is only triggered once the `#` char is found, and it is easier to look for a static char than to check for the lookbehind pattern at each location in the string (as is the case with the second regex).